# Altbeacons intergration

Tags: android, altbeacon

So I'm having issues tracking down why binding the beacons to an `IntentService` doesn't work.  I know that the mBase context is null so when the bind is attempted it throws a null.

What I don't know is how to propagate the Context forward, or how I should have the beacon consumer set up.  The library works when I attach it to a the mainActivity as a beaconConsumer but not the internal library structure that handles the geofences and location updates.

While that might be my issue in having too many interfaces on one class, I doubt it.  I followed the tutorial only splitting up the required parts into other classes rather than the mainActivity.

https://github.com/ccoulton/android-sdk, `LocationManager` is what I'm trying to connect it to, but no such luck

logcat for unbind

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.google.android.gms.location.GeofencingEvent.hasError()' on a null object reference
        at com.qwasi.sdk.QwasiLocationManager.onHandleIntent(QwasiLocationManager.java:261)
        at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

Answer (score 0):

I may have fixed it by putting the bind the onActivityCreated lifetime event rather than on Activity resumed...  Not sure why but hey it may work...